# Second order differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$y^{\prime \prime} + \frac{1}{2}y^{\prime} = 10$

solution for homogeneous $y^{\prime \prime} + \frac{1}{2}y^{\prime} = 0$ is $y= A+Be^{-0.5t}$

how do i solve for the particular solution LHS?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. Here it is mandatory to show own work. What are your thoughts? Any idea of an ansatz? Also, please use [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) when writing your question, since it increases readability. You can edit your question fixing this.

Comment: @mickep already taken care of

Answer (score 2):

You may use special guesses for this case. Since the RHS is a constant and the LHS is a **second** order linear operator, it seems reasonable to try a solution which is a polynomial of order **two**

$${y_p} = A + Bx + C{x^2}$$

and try to find the constants by putting it into the equation

$$\eqalign{
  & {\left( {A + Bx + C{x^2}} \right)^{\prime \prime }} + \frac{1}{2}{\left( {A + Bx + C{x^2}} \right)^\prime } = 2C + \frac{1}{2}\left( {B + 2Cx} \right)  \cr 
  & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, = \left( {\frac{1}{2}B + 2C} \right) + Cx = 10 \cr} $$

and hence you conclude that

$$\left\{ \matrix{
  {1 \over 2}B + 2C = 10 \hfill \cr 
  C = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right.\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\left\{ \matrix{
  B = 20 \hfill \cr 
  C = 0 \hfill \cr}  \right.$$

and finally your particular solution becomes

$${y_p} = A + 20x$$

where you can choose $A$ as you wish. So the simplest one is to take $A=0$ and hence

$${y_p} = 20x$$

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find one solution. The simplest is $\varphi(t) = A+B\exp(-0.5t) + 10y$. After that you need to see, that $\varphi(t) - y(t)$ is also the solution of LHS, if $y(t)$ is a solution of homogeneous. So you need to find two linear independent solutions: $\varphi(t) - y_i(t)$ where $i=1,2$, and $y_i$ are two solutions of homogeneous.